# Form action attribute set to null not including php script

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to post a html form to itself but somehow i'm not getting results. I have two php files. One file is named form.php and looks like this

```html
<form action = "" method = "post">
First name: <input name ="first_name" type = "test" size = 20" maxlength = "20"><p>
Second name name: <input name ="second_name" type = "test" size = 20" maxlength = "20"><p>
<input name = "submit" type="submit" value = "submit">
</form>
```

The other one is named names.php and includes form.php

```
<?Php

if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
include "form.php";
}
else{
echo $_POST['first_name'];
echo $_POST['second_name'];
?>
```

The problem is that names are not echoing. I know this looks like a simple problem but funny enough it does not work for me. I'm at my wits end on this one. Is it a browser problem? Is it a html problem or is it a php problem?

Comment: do `var_dump($_POST);` before `if `  statement to check what is being posted  and your  `else` is missing closing bracket.

Comment: I assume the initial / only file you are opening in the browser is `names.php`?

Comment: After appending the closing bracket } for the else condition and changing "test" to "text" still no names echoing. Something to ponder though if i run /localhost/names.php i get desired results. I have also tried the var_dump[$_POST] solution but in vain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in closing of ("). First fix that. I hope your code will work

```
<form action = "" method = "post">
First name: 
<input name ="first_name" type = "text" size = "20" maxlength = "20"><p>
Second name name: 
<input name ="second_name" type = "text" size = "20" maxlength = "20"><p>
<input name = "submit" type="submit" value = "submit">
</form>
```

Comment: @Maina In your code you have written size = "20 maxlength="20" where as it should be size ="20" maxlength="20"

Comment: Thanks @Manish for this but still not working. I think it is best to insert "names.php" on the action attribute because leaving it blank does not work

Comment: Any leads as to why a blank "" action attribute refuses to work while most PHP books suggest they should be used?

Comment: The action attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted. if you do not want to set action attribute the data will not be sent to any other file and you have to write all php code on same page.

Answer (score 0):

1) Change type="test" to type="text"

2) Close bracket } is missing